# forms.CharField(initial = "")

Tags: django, django-forms

My task to make pre-populated content of the page, like this:
[content](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NPfTJ.png)

```
content = "Sample text"
content = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea, initial = content)
```

I need something like above, can you help me with realising that in code

```
class EditPageForm(forms.Form):
    content = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea)

def editPage(request, title):
    content = util.get_entry(title)
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = EditPageForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            new_content = form.cleaned_data["content"]
            util.save_entry(title, new_content)
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse("encyclopedia:entry", kwargs={'title': title})) 
    EditPageForm.initial = content
    return render(request, "encyclopedia/editpage.html", {
        "form": NewSearchForm,
        "editPageForm": EditPageForm,
        "title": title
    })
```

Html code:

```
<form action="{% url 'encyclopedia:editpage' title=title%}" method="post">
    <div>
        <h3>Content:</h3>
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ editPageForm }}
    </div>
    <input type="Submit">
    </form>
```

Comment: Could you please specify what about your code is not working? Please include information about troubleshooting you have done to try and determine where the problem is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank everyone for help, the solution was found.

```
return render(request, "encyclopedia/editpage.html", {
        "form": NewSearchForm,
        "editPageForm": EditPageForm(initial={'content': content}),
        "title": title
    })
```

Now how that looks like, [image]

Answer (score 0):

You can pass an [**`initial=…`** parameter [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/forms/api/#django.forms.Form.initial) to the form with as value a dictionary with initial values:

```
from django.shortcuts import redirect

def editPage(request, title):
    content = util.get_entry(title)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        editPageForm = EditPageForm(request.POST, initial={'content': content})
        if form.is_valid():
            new_content = form.cleaned_data['content']
            util.save_entry(title, new_content)
        return redirect('encyclopedia:entry', title=title)
    else:
        editPageForm = EditPageForm(, initial={'content': content})
    return render(request, 'encyclopedia/editpage.html', {
        'form': NewSearchForm,
        'editPageForm': editPageForm,
        'title': title
    })
```

That being said, it might be better to work with models and a [**`ModelForm`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/forms/modelforms/) since this can remove a lot of boilerplate code.

Answer (score 0):

You can use widget attributes to add placeholder text that you'd like in your form which can be dynamic and less lines to add.

```
class EditPageForm(forms.Form):
    content = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea(attrs={'placeholder': 'THIS IS MY PLACEHOLDER TEXT'}))
```